# Batch File that will Backup My Files?

Tags: batch-file, copy, backup, erase

How would I go about making a batch file that empties a backup folder on my PC and then copies over the data on my USB to the folder. And then each evening my files would be backed up by simple clicking on the file. I don't have a very big grasp on how batch files work. Could somebody point me in the right direction as to what this would look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
ROBOCOPY f:\myusb c:\myfolder /mir
```

It will copy from source (the usb) to target (the hd) from/to indicated folders all the new and updated files, ignore and leave all the non changed files and remove from target all the files not present in source.

Comment: +1 Robocopy with `/mir` is very powerful, but **beware** don't get the target folder wrong.  It can wipe enormous quantities of data if you pick the root directory, or the wrong folder/drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
XCOPY /s "C:\folder\" "F:\"
```

30sec on startpage/google

Will not work on W8 it seems thought

EDIT: for Win8:

```
ROBOCOPY /E C:\folder\ F:\folder, /E
```

is for copying all subfolder in the folder.

Comment: Damn. I would be running this file on Win8. I'll try looking for something for Windows 8.

Comment: Search for Robocopy, it was mentionned it is the equivalent of xcopy

Comment: ROBOCOPY /E C:\folder\ F:\folder, /E is for copying all subfolder in the folder.